# Sim900 GSM module keeps disconnecting when it's used as a TCP Client

Tags: networking, gsm, at-command, gprs, sim900

I’m trying to interface a Sim900 GSM module (This one: http://www.elecfreaks.com/store/gprsgsm-moduleefcom-pro-efcompro-p-450.html) with a Tiva C microcontroller to initiate a TCP connection using a sim card.

The problem is that once the GSM module is connected to the server the internet of the GSM module auto disconnects and I have to reset it, but also sometimes it connects successfully to the server then auto disconnects after receiving any reply from the server, Although it's the same AT commands. why does that keep happening?

**Edit:**

These are the commands I'm using and the corresponding responses in order:

```
ATE0
\r\nOK\r\n

AT+CREG?
\r\n+CREG: 0,1\r\n\r\n

AT+CGATT?
\r\n+CGATT: 1\r\n\r\n

AT+CIPMUX=0
\r\nOK\r\n

AT+CGATT=1
\r\nOK\r\n

AT+CSTT
\r\nOK\r\n

AT+CIICR
\r\nOK\r\n

AT+CIFSR
the IP address of the GSM module

AT+CIPSTART="TCP",Server_IP,Server_Port
\r\nOK\r\n\r\nCONNECT
```

Sometimes the GSM disconnects right after the previous response
Sometimes it keeps working normally and sends the request to the server, but disconnects during the reply from the server after receiving few bytes.

The send command and its reply:

```
AT+CIPSEND
\r\n> 

"The message"
\r\nSEND OK\r\n
```

I'm sure that the problem isn't with the IP address and Port number because I tested them using telnet.

Also sometimes the request reaches the server, but the GSM auto disconnects during the server reply.

Comment: You need to add the relevant parts of the code to the question.

Comment: @hlovdal I added them